# create array entry for each paragraph in a text file

Tags: python, arrays, text, paragraph

Is there an easy way in python to create an array entry for each paragraph in a text file with the new line character being the demarcation for a new entry?

The idea being that if my doc has 5 paragraphs with a new line between each, there will be 5 separate entries in the array.

Thanks.

Comment: Paragraphs can be multiline, correct?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=file.readlines#file.readlines

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Paragraphs can be more than one line. I suppose I need an empty line as the marker to start a new array element. Apologies for the lack of clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
    f = open('sample_text.txt', 'r')

    data = f.read()
    paragraphs = data.split("\n\n")

    paragraphs[:] = (value for value in paragraphs if value != '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a very easy way to do this.  You parse the text file line by line.  Store each line in a temp object.  If a line is only one char long, and it is the new line char, then assign that temp object to the appropriate array position, then start appending the lines into the a new temp object.  Look up basic python syntax to complete this as it should be fairly easy.